# How to maintain single list instead of having multiple lists using linq?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have to order the list values. Where the first value must remain the same. Remaining values should order by descending.

Eg:

list<> repository={"car","bike","airplane","train","ship"};

After order the list excepted result be:

repository={"car","train","ship" ,"bike”, “airplane”};

How can I simplify the code? Without using more than two list variable.

```
       List<Automobile> vehicle = new List<Automobile >();
       List<Automobile> vehicle1 = new List<Automobile>();
       List<Automobile > vehicle2 = new List<Automobile>();

            using (var entity = new AutomobileEntity())
            {
              vehicle = (from details in entity.dbVechiles.Where(i => i.IsActive == true)
                         join sp in entity.dbSpeed.Where(i => i.IsActive) on details.vspeed equals sp.vspeed
                         select new Automobile
                         {
                           Vid = details.vId,
                           VName = details.vName,
                           Vspeed = sp.vspeed,
                           VRate = sp.vrate
                         }).ToList();
            }

  vehicle1 = vehicle.Where(x => x. VName == "BMW").OrderByDescending(x => x. Vid).ToList();
  vehicle2 = vehicle.Where(x => x. VName != "BMW").OrderByDescending(x => x. Vid).ToList();

  vehicle1.AddRange(vehicle2);

  return vehicle1;
```

Comment: Did you try the skip or take methods?

Comment: with simplify you mean, the code should be shorter or more readable?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace:

```
vehicle.Where(x => x. VName == "BMW").OrderByDescending(x => x. Vid).ToList();
vehicle.Where(x => x. VName != "BMW").OrderByDescending(x => x. Vid).ToList();
```

with:

```
vehicle.OrderBy(x => x.VName == "BMW").ThenByDescending(x => x.Vid).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> repository = new List<string>(new[] { "car", "bike", "airplane", "train", "ship" });
var result = repository.Take(1).Union(repository.Skip(1).OrderByDescending(x => x));
```

returns

{"car","train","ship" ,"bike”, “airplane”}

so in your case use

so in your case use return

```
vehicle.Take(1).Union(vehicle.Skip(1).OrderByDescending(x => x.Vid));
```

as mentioned by Marc if you want to prevent duplicates from being removed you can concat the rest of the list or prepend the first item as he suggests.

```
var result = repository.Take(1).Concat(repository.Skip(1).OrderByDescending(x => x));
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you exactly want but here is a way to order a list but keeping the first one there:

```
List<string> repository = new List<string>{ "car","bike","airplane","train","ship"};
repository = repository.Skip(1).OrderBy(value => value).Prepend(repository.First()).ToList();
```

Edit:
Just saw that @Mr. Belis was a bit quicker with a similar Solution but if you use the ".Union" function you have to be aware that it will also cause a distinct on your list. So duplicates in your list will be removed.

Comment: Agreed, Union would remove the duplicates on a list of strings, for the reference type 'Automobile' this would depend on the Equals implementation for the items.

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
using (var entity = new AutomobileEntity())
{
    return (from details in entity.dbVechiles.Where(i => i.IsActive == true)
               join sp in entity.dbSpeed.Where(i => i.IsActive) on details.vspeed equals sp.vspeed
               select new Automobile
               {
                   Vid = details.vId,
                   VName = details.vName,
                   Vspeed = sp.vspeed,
                   VRate = sp.vrate
               }).OrderBy(x => x.VName).ThenByDescending(x => x.Vid).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done in a single query, although I am not sure about use of LINQ keywords.

```
var list = new List<string> {"car", "bike", "airplane", "train", "ship"};

list = (from x in list
      let firstItem = list.First()
      orderby x descending
      orderby x != firstItem
      select x).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option you could do for the same result.

```
repository.OrderBy(x=> x!= repository.First()).ThenByDescending(x=>x);
```